# Phonegap - Javascript don't working

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova

I have a problem, when i try to make a phonegap build and test it on my android phone javascript don't run.

I have simple config.xml file, and there is a preview of my index.html's head :

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>My app</title>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script  type="text/javascript" src = "phonegap.js" > </script>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, user-scalable=yes">
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Mobile_style.css"><link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand:700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script  type="text/javascript" src = "phonegap.js" > </script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

function onBodyLoad()
        {                    
            document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
        }


        function onDeviceReady()
        {
            // do your thing!
        }   
   </script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
  window.onload = function()
  {

      MY JS CODE

}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="onBodyLoad()">

      MY HTML

</body>
```

I have two html files, the index.html and the game.html, i have the same links and scripts in the game's head.

i have try to put my code on the   but thats not working.

I have search some hours but i can solve the problem.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: You have `cordova.js` and `phonegap.js` declarations repeated twice. Delete the last 2 and delete 1 of the others. You can only have 1 version of jQuery declared in your page, and a matching jQueryUI addition.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but where i need to put my js code ?

Answer (score 1):

You should include only one version of jquery. Also you don't need both cordova.js and phonegap.js, choose one script.

Your code may look much more cleaner:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>My app</title>


    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, user-scalable=yes">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Mobile_style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand:700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="phonegap.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

        function onDeviceReady() {
            alert("Device is ready");
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>

    MY HTML

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should include the other script declarations and remove the redundant ones so the OP knows what we're both talking about.

Comment: thanks for the answer but i don't understand what is the "refundant". where i need to put my js code ?

Comment: @Sanalol look at the above example. All the "redundant" `<script>` tags are removed. Although, looks like he completely removed `jquery.min.js`, but kept `jquery-ui.min.js`. If you don't know what we're talking about here, there's not much we can do. I would suggest finding a programmer friend to guide you at that point.

Comment: @Sanalol, if you don't understand what "redundant" stands for, try to answer, why did you include every script and css, maybe this way you'll get into this.

Comment: thanks for the answers, and sorry i don't understand very well english, it's ok now. My js script need to be in <script type="text/javascript" src="phonegap.js"></script> tags ? Thanks a lot

Comment: @Sanalol You can put your js code either inside script tags or you can do it in external javascript file which is best practice. I have a feeling that you are on a very beginning of your js programming path, you should take some lessons. I advise you to go through some youtube javascript tutorials, there are lots of them. Just do everything what's tutorial about, this will help you to get initial skills. Please don't forget to mark my answer as accepted if it was helpful. Regards.

Comment: Thanks for your help ! i ask you this for phonegap, that's my first app, if i open my index.html on firefox, javascript is ok, but with phonegap i have no javascript. i know  i can put my js code in script tags or external file, i just want to know why with the phonegap build my js not run and if is better to put the js code on the script tags with src="phonegap.js or if it's better to put this on an external file.

Comment: I don't know why your js doesn't run, although I don't have installed environment for phonegap, and I can't test my code example, I'm pretty sure the code sample will fire alert with javascript. Try to make clean phonegap project with index.html as in example above and test it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i have tested with the alert and it's ok (i see the alert), but when i try to replace the alert by my js code (on the function "ondeviceready" of after this) and my script don't run. on firefox or chrome no problem, only a problem with the phonegap build on my phone

Comment: @Sanalol Extended discussions are not encouraged here, I advise you to create new topic on your new problem or try to look up more help in stackoverflow chat.

Comment: it's the same problem, my js code don't run on phonegap build, but it's ok on firefox